# How to access ArcSDE metadata using OGR?

Tags: gdal, enterprise-geodatabase, ogr

I'm trying to get a list of all layers in an ArcSDE database hosted in oracle

here is the command I'm using:

```
ogrinfo -al SDE:localhost,5151,sde,sde,sde
```

Note: I've replace the database, username and password values with sde

When I execute the above I get the following message:

```
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `SDE:localhost,5151,sde,sde,sde
Following drivers.
  -> OCI
  -> SOSI
  -> ESRI Shapefile
  -> MapInfo File
  -> UK .NTF
  -> SDTS
  -> TIGER
  -> S57
  -> DGN
  -> VRT
  -> REC
  -> Memory
  -> BNA
  -> CSV
  -> NAS
  -> GML
  -> GPX
  -> KML
  -> GeoJSON
  -> Interlis 1
  -> Interlis 2
  -> GMT
  -> GPKG
  -> SQLite
  -> ODBC
  -> WAsP
  -> PGeo
  -> MSSQLSpatial
  -> OGDI
  -> PostgreSQL
  -> MySQL
  -> PCIDSK
  -> OpenFileGDB
  -> XPlane
  -> AVCBin
  -> AVCE00
  -> DXF
  -> Geoconcept
  -> GeoRSS
  -> GPSTrackMaker
  -> VFK
  -> PGDump
  -> OSM
  -> GPSBabel
  -> SUA
  -> OpenAir
  -> PDS
  -> WFS
  -> HTF
  -> AeronavFAA
  -> Geomedia
  -> EDIGEO
  -> GFT
  -> GME
  -> SVG
  -> CouchDB
  -> Idrisi
  -> ARCGEN
  -> SEGUKOOA
  -> SEGY
  -> XLS
  -> ODS
  -> XLSX
  -> ElasticSearch
  -> PDF
  -> Walk
  -> CartoDB
  -> SXF
```

I'm assuming that since SDE isn't in the list that is the problem.

Any idea of how to add this support?

according to http://www.gdal.org/drv_sde.html

It isn't compiled by default and requires the ArcSDE drivers

I'm unsure how to install this correctly

Comment: looks like I do need to include the ArcSDE Libraries: https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ArcSDE however no windows instructions are provided I need to figure out how to get the arcSDE C library from ESRI as well

Comment: I have the same problem, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Yeah I think you are out of luck unless you get a copy of the esri dlls

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to compile GDAL to get SDE support. Detailed instructions how to do this are provided in the answer to the question [Get GDAL up and running with ArcSDE enabled](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219660/get-gdal-up-and-running-with-arcsde-enabled). You just need access to the server where you are running ArcSDE.