# Get GDAL up and running with ArcSDE enabled

Tags: raster, gdal, enterprise-geodatabase

I want to migrate rasters from ArcSDE 9.2 to Postgresql.

I have access to a ArcSDE server with several large raster datasets (mosaics) in ArcSDE 9.2. I can use ArcCatalog, ArcMap and ArcToolbox to view and manage the datasets. If I use the Export Raster tool, it fails, since the generated tif is larger that 4Gb.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to compile GDAL with SDE support. I have access to the SDE dlls installed on the server, but I don't have the ArcSDE Development Kit to compile GDAL with SDE support. I was able to [compile GDAL](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingOnWindows), but not with SDE support.

I would like to split the raster mosaics. How can I split the mosaic in several smaller rasters?

Comment: I would recommend you abandon trying to place images in a database. Instead, I would recommend locating your source images and  use a mosaic dataset. If you want to compare performance, you should locate the original images and load them using both tools. If you *have* to export  tiles out of the database, you'll need to **edit** the question  to specify the exact versions of all available software.  Note that ArcGIS cannot read rasters stored in PostGIS rasters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to export all data (vector and raster) from ArcSDE using GDAL. **To have ArcSDE support in GDAL it is not necessary to compile GDAL**. If you have access to an ArcSDE installation, that's enough. You will use `dlls` that are already installed on the server. You don’t need any media from ESRI, like ArcSDE Development Kit.

To this data transfer, I used a [free Windows 7 virtual machine from Microsoft](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) to run GDAL with SDE support.

### Get GDAL up and running with ArcSDE enabled

- Download MS4W (select [ms4w_3.0.6](http://www.ms4w.com/release/archive/zip/ms4w_3.0.6.zip) from the archives, not the last
  version)
- Unzip it to c:\
- Copy `gdal_SDE.dll` and `ogr_SDE.dll` from
  `c:\ms4w\gdalplugins\ignored\sde-9.2` to `c:\ms4w\gdalplugins`

If you install MS4W on the same server where ArcSDE is installed, this is enough. It you are using another machine, you also need:

- Copy your `c:\arcgis\ArcSDE` folder from the server running ArcSDE to the same location on your local machine (the entire folder zipped is just 32Mb)
- Update you environment variables:

  - Add to `PATH` `C:\arcgis\ArcSDE\sqlexe\bin;C:\ms4w\tools\gdal-ogr`
  - Create `SDEHOME` with `C:\arcgis\ArcSDE\sqlexe\`

### Check SDE support

Open the command prompt.

```
C:\Users\IEUser>cd c:\ms4w
C:\ms4w>setenv.bat
C:\ms4w>gdalinfo --formats
Supported Formats:
  SDE (ro): ESRI ArcSDE
  VRT (rw+v): Virtual Raster
  GTiff (rw+v): GeoTIFF
  NITF (rw+v): National Imagery Transmission Format
  (...)

C:\ms4w>ogrinfo --formats
Supported Formats:
  -> "SDE" (read/write)
  -> "ESRI Shapefile" (read/write)
  -> "MapInfo File" (read/write)
  -> "UK .NTF" (readonly)
  -> "SDTS" (readonly)
  -> "TIGER" (read/write)
  (...)
```

Test with your own ArcSDE data

```
C:\ms4w>ogrinfo -ro -so -al SDE:192.168.100.32,5159,FINAL,sdeuser,sdepassword,final.SDE.REDMUNICIPAL,sde.DEFAULT
INFO: Open of `SDE:192.168.100.32,5159,FINAL,sdeuser,sdepassword,final.SDE.REDEMUNICIPAL,sd
.DEFAULT'
      using driver `SDE' successful.

Layer name: FINAL.SDE.REDEMUNICIPAL
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 32974
Extent: (-42781.579992, 113467.000009) - (-31999.999950, 129415.940056)
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCS["Datum_73_Hayford_Gauss_IPCC",
    GEOGCS["GCS_Datum_73",
    (...)

C:\ms4w>gdalinfo SDE:192.168.100.32,5158,raster,sdeuser,sdepassword,raster.SDE.REN
Driver: SDE/ESRI ArcSDE
Files: none associated
Size is 6693, 8639
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["Datum_73_Hayford_Gauss_IPCC",
    GEOGCS["GCS_Datum_73",
        DATUM["Datum_73",
            SPHEROID["International_1924",6378388.0,297.0]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    (...)
```

### Use GDAL to get data from ArcSDE

For my use case, I’ve transferred vector data directly from ArcSDE to Postgis with:

```
ogr2ogr -append -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=192.168.100.82 user=geobox dbname=final password=geobox active_schema=teste" SDE:192.168.100.32,5159,FINAL,sdeuser,sdepassword,final.SDE.VIALARGA,sde.DEFAULT -nln vialarga -s_srs EPSG:27493 -t_srs EPSG:3763
```

To transfer raster data, I’ve created `tif` files, for smaller raster datasets.

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -co PROFILE=BASELINE -co TFW=YES -co COMPRESS=LZW -co PREDICTOR=2 -a_srs EPSG:27493 SDE:192.168.100.32,5158,raster,sdeuser,sdepassword,raster.SDE.RAN ran27493.tif
```

For the larger datasets, I’ve sliced the images into tiles. I use the same `gdal_translate` as above with an additional `-srcwin` parameter generated by small python script from the question [Splitting raster into smaller chunks using GDAL?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14712/splitting-raster-into-smaller-chunks-using-gdal)