# GDAL with ArcSDE driver

Tags: gdal, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

I am attempting to use GDAL/OGR to read from an SDE enabled database (MS SQL). I have tried the steps located [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219660/get-gdal-up-and-running-with-arcsde-enabled) but do not have access to the database server. I am also using a GDAL installation for python downloaded and installed from [GISInternals](http://www.gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1500-gdal-2-2-1-mapserver-7-0-6.zip). (`gdal-202-1500-core.msi` and `GDAL-2.2.1.win32-py2.7.msi`) so my setup is a little different.

**What I have tried**

1. I downloaded the archived [ms4w_3.0.6](http://www.ms4w.com/release/archive/zip/ms4w_3.0.6.zip) and copied the `ogr_SDE.dll` and `gdal_SDE.dll` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdalplugins`
2. Downloaded and installed the ArcSDE binaries from the MyEsri site. Verified  the `SDEHOME` path was set correctly.
3. Add `C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\ArcSDE\sqlexe\bin;C:\ms4w_3.0.6\ms4w\tools\gdal-ogr`to path.

However, when I check for available formats, I see this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdalplugins>ogrinfo --formats
ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdalplugins\ogr_S
DE.dll
126: The specified module could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdalplugins\ogr_S
DE.dll
126: The specified module could not be found.

Supported Formats:
  -> "ESRI Shapefile" (read/write)
  -> "MapInfo File" (read/write)
  -> "UK .NTF" (readonly)
  -> "SDTS" (readonly)
  -> "TIGER" (read/write)
  -> "S57" (read/write)
  -> "DGN" (read/write)
  -> "VRT" (readonly)
  -> "REC" (readonly)
  -> "Memory" (read/write)
  -> "BNA" (read/write)
  -> "CSV" (read/write)
  -> "NAS" (readonly)
  -> "GML" (read/write)
  -> "GPX" (read/write)
  -> "LIBKML" (read/write)
  -> "KML" (read/write)
  -> "GeoJSON" (read/write)
  -> "Interlis 1" (read/write)
  -> "Interlis 2" (read/write)
  -> "GMT" (read/write)
  -> "GPKG" (read/write)
  -> "SQLite" (read/write)
  -> "ODBC" (read/write)
  -> "WAsP" (read/write)
  -> "PGeo" (readonly)
  -> "MSSQLSpatial" (read/write)
  -> "PostgreSQL" (read/write)
  -> "MySQL" (read/write)
  -> "PCIDSK" (read/write)
  -> "OpenFileGDB" (readonly)
  -> "XPlane" (readonly)
  -> "AVCBin" (readonly)
  -> "AVCE00" (readonly)
  -> "DXF" (read/write)
  -> "Geoconcept" (read/write)
  -> "GeoRSS" (read/write)
  -> "GPSTrackMaker" (read/write)
  -> "VFK" (readonly)
  -> "PGDump" (read/write)
  -> "OSM" (readonly)
  -> "GPSBabel" (read/write)
  -> "SUA" (readonly)
  -> "OpenAir" (readonly)
  -> "PDS" (readonly)
  -> "WFS" (readonly)
  -> "HTF" (readonly)
  -> "AeronavFAA" (readonly)
  -> "Geomedia" (readonly)
  -> "EDIGEO" (readonly)
  -> "GFT" (read/write)
  -> "GME" (read/write)
  -> "SVG" (readonly)
  -> "CouchDB" (read/write)
  -> "Idrisi" (readonly)
  -> "ARCGEN" (readonly)
  -> "SEGUKOOA" (readonly)
  -> "SEGY" (readonly)
  -> "ODS" (read/write)
  -> "XLSX" (read/write)
  -> "ElasticSearch" (read/write)
  -> "PDF" (read/write)
  -> "Walk" (readonly)
  -> "CartoDB" (readonly)
  -> "SXF" (readonly)

C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdalplugins>
```

I am simply looking to read data from the SDE database with GDAL/OGR.

---

Looks like I am trying to connect to ArcSDE version 10.2.1. Not sure if its even possible to connect to a 10+ SDE with GDAL.

Comment: Did you run `setenv.bat` before `ogrinfo`?
In my `setenv.bat` I have several environment variables that needs to be defined, like `set GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=\ms4w\gdalplugins`.

Comment: @jgrocha I did not run `setenv.bat`. My GDAL installation is not from `MS4W`, but from the gisinternals site. I am only using the `SDE` plugins from `MS4W`. The installation process I used is described [here](http://cartometric.com/blog/2011/10/17/install-gdal-on-windows/). Regaurdless, my `GDAL_DRIVER_PATH` is set to `C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdalplugins`, among the other required variables. Since my primary reason for using the GISInternals install is to use the `osgeo` library via python, id rather try and make this work then use the MS4W installation.

Comment: So I installed `ms4w` and ran `setenv.bat`, esured all env. variables were set correctly, installed ArcSDE 10.2.1, set the `SDEHOME` variable and added the `bin` directory to the path. Now when i run `ogrinfo --formats` I get `ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\ms4w\gdalplugins\ogr_SDE.dll 193%1 is not a valid win32 application`

Comment: Does `gdalinfo --formats` reports the same error?
I tested GDAL with SDE support to connect to ArcSDE v9.2. I don't know if ArcSDE 10.x is supported.

Comment: It produces the same error. I have doubts the driver supports connecting to ArcSDE 10+ .